# Deployment on Vercel failed (js file and css file in assets folder while they should be in dist folder)

Tags: reactjs, deployment, vite, vercel

i'm using React + Vite, i'm having troubles trying to deploy my app on Vercel. In fact the app is deployed and online, but there's only the index.html file that is deployed, the js file and css file are not deployed cause when i build the app, it creates the dist folder, and these two files are in the assets folder while they should be at the root of the dist folder, like  the index.html.

I build the project, the dist folder appear, in this folder there's an other folder "assets", inside of it, there are the js and css file, is it supposed to be that way ? i don't know cause when i deploy it on Vercel, there's only a white page, the page of the index.html.

Comment: Hope you are referencing your js and css scripts in your html file. Can we see your html markup?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Problem solved, in fact i didn't have to build the project, Vercel handles the build, so now , i deployed it and it is working. :)